# How to use injected providers in a controller with a packaged dynamic module in nestjs

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, nestjs

I couldn't seem to find any related question to my problem on here, so i decided to ask my first question, please be gentle :>

I want to provide an endpoint for frontend logging in several of our backends that use nestjs.

To solve this, i want to use a dynamic module that exposes said endpoint and package it as an npm package to be used in other applications.

I inject a logger into the controller via an injection token and the logging service via nestjs standard dependency injection.

The problem now is, after publishing the module, installing it in another application, the service i injected via nestjs standard DI is undefined.

I tried to follow the nestjs documentation as closly as possible when it comes to [dynamic modules](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/dynamic-modules).

I also tried to retrieve the service via [ModuleRef](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/module-ref), but still the same problem. In this case, `moduleRef` is undefined.

Here is basically all of the involved code:

**frontend-log.module.ts:**

```
import { DynamicModule, Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { FrontendLogService } from "./frontend-log.service";
import { Logger } from "./interfaces/logger";
import { FrontendLogController } from "./frontend-log.controller";

@Module({})
export class FrontendLogModule {
  static forRoot(logger: Logger): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: FrontendLogModule,
      controllers: [FrontendLogController],
      providers: [FrontendLogService, { provide: "LOGGER", useValue: logger }],
    };
  }
}
```

**frontend-log.controller.ts:**

```
import { Body, Controller, Inject, Post, Req } from "@nestjs/common";
import { FrontendLogMessage } from "../model/frontend-log-message";
import { Request } from "express";
import { RequestWithToken } from "../model/request-with-token";
import { Logger } from "./interfaces/logger";
import { ArrayMaxSize, ArrayMinSize, ValidateNested } from "class-validator";
import { Type } from "class-transformer";
import { FrontendLogService } from "./frontend-log.service";

class FrontendLogData {
  @Type(() => FrontendLogMessage)
  @ArrayMinSize(1)
  @ArrayMaxSize(20)
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  messages: FrontendLogMessage[];
}

@Controller()
export class FrontendLogController {
  constructor(
    @Inject("LOGGER") private logger: Logger,
    private logService: FrontendLogService
  ) {}

  @Post("log")
  public log(@Req() req: Request, @Body() data: FrontendLogData) {
    this.logService.logFrontendMessages(  // logService is undefined here
      this.logger,
      data.messages,
      (req as RequestWithToken).kauth.grant.access_token.content
    );
  }
}
```

**frontend-log.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { FrontendLogMessage } from "../model/frontend-log-message";
import { AccessTokenContent } from "../model/request-with-token";
import { Logger } from "./interfaces/logger";

@Injectable()
export class FrontendLogService {
  public logFrontendMessages(
    logger: Logger,
    data: FrontendLogMessage[],
    accessToken?: AccessTokenContent
  ) {
    const user = accessToken
      ? `${accessToken.name} (${accessToken.sub})`
      : "anonymous";
    data.forEach((logEntry) => {
      logger.log(logEntry.level, `[FRONTEND] [${user}] ${logEntry.message}`);
    });
  }
}
```

I then build the package and publish it.

After installing it in the consuming project I import the `frontend-log.module` into the `AppModule` as follows:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    // ...
    FrontendLogModule.forRoot(getLogger('debug')),
  ],
  controllers: [
    // ...
  ],
  providers: [
    // ...
  ],
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  // ...
}
```

When i then try to post to the `/log` endpoint via Postman, the following error occurs:

```
[Nest] 15280  - 26.10.2022, 09:03:50   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'logFrontendMessages')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'logFrontendMessages')                                                                                                                
    at FrontendLogController.log
```

This tells me, the `frontend-log.controller` works properly, since the `log` endpoint is exposed as expected.

**So my question:** What am I doing wrong here, is there something i am not considering, when it comes to publishing nestjs Modules over npm? Or am I doing some rookie mistake here?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).